# Duplicate with another StackExchange site

Tags: discussion, duplicates

What should we do with https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12478/is-there-a-gis-application-for-android? The question is equally on-topic for both Android and GIS Stack Exchange.

Comment: Should we close them? As it stands now, the question cannot be answered without duplicating GIS' perfectly good answer and there is no appropriate close/duplicate reason for this kind if case.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pity that StackExchange isn't a bit more intelligent with cross-SE site links. I'd say that the questions are related, but there's likely to be a slightly different focus by answerers on each site. I'd have thought an entry in the "Linked Questions" section would be the right way to do it, but not currently possible.

Comment: Please see my added comment.

Answer (score 1):

In general it's fine to have overlapping questions, as long as they weren't cross-posted by the same user (without appropriate reason).  Linking in a comment is a good idea though.

This isn't generally done on beta sites though (the beta question is closed), although you'd have to ask the SE team for the reasoning there.

Comment: Please see my added comment.

Comment: @LieRyan I still think it's fine to stay here. An answer pointing to GIS and summarizing wouldn't be amiss though. If you think SE should have a better way of dealing with these I would bring it up on MSO, since it's likely to get more attention there (if it hasn't already been discussed).